# Can a "=>" Function Lose Context?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an ES6 "arrow" function which is used as a (Knockout) subscription handler:

```
this.foo = 'test'
callback = () => console.log(this.foo)
bar.subscribe(callback);
```

According to MDN:

> Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context

So I would expect that when the `callback` gets called, it would log `'test'`.  It doesn't though.  When I put a debugger in, I can see that `this` is actually a `ko.subscription` (which of course doesn't have a `foo` property).

I can fix things by manually binding the callback:

```
callback = callback.bind(this)
```

but as I understood things that shouldn't be necessary because my `this` should have been bound before `callback` ever got to `subscribe`.

Can someone please explain what I'm not understanding about the new `=>` operator, and when it does/doesn't preserve context?

Comment: Are you using ES6 directly in the browser or Babel or .. ?

Comment: What is the context for that first bit of code? Like, where is it? In a method somewhere?

Comment: @Matt directly in the browser (I will use Babel for production, but was seeing this in my development environment, in Chrome, before Babel even got involved).

Comment: @pointy Yes it was a method (defined in the class's constructor), so the context was the object the method was defined on.

Comment: Your expectation is correct. The `=>` should be equal to your `bind` alternative. So I don't know what the issue is here, unless this example is some sort of summarized code that doesn't match the real context

Comment: Well, how was *that* method invoked?  You really haven't shown much code here. Arrow functions get their implicit `this` bound at creation time.

Comment: Also if you are calling `subscribe` with the second (`callbackTarget` parameter, the callback will have its context bound to that: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/8decc433942d7413b47768e0f45c304e8f15aa09/src/subscribables/subscribable.js#L42

Comment: you can't use arrow functions for methods.

Comment: Arrow functions are working as documented in my Chrome console.

Comment: @machineghost  Does it fail in Firefox as well as Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  It did turn out to be a browser issue, not a misunderstanding of `=>`.  Please see my answer if you're curious about the details.

Answer (score 1):

First off, thanks everyone for your help.  It turns out this is just some sort of screwy Chrome developer tools bug.

Here's my original (not simpified) code:

```
this.snapshot_profile = ko.observable('1');
this.foo = 5;
this.snapshot_profile.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(this.foo);
    debugger
    // rest of the method
});
```

As it turns out, the `console.log` will correctly return `5`.  However, if you pause on the debugger line and hover over `this`, you will see that it is not an instance of my class, but rather a `ko.subscription`.  If I "inspect" `this` in the console, it will look like this:

```
callback: (value)
dispose: ()
disposeCallback: ()
target: observable()
__proto__: ko.subscription
```

**not** like an instance of my class.  However (strangely) the `console.log` line will correctly log `5`.

All of the above can be "fixed" by binding the function, either directly or through Knockout's binding mechanism.  This is what confused me: in the debugger binding/not binding the arrow function actually did change things!

But, it looks like it really didn't change anything meaningful; it just exposed a bug in Chrome's debugger.

Comment: Did you report it? Can you link it?

Comment: Complications. If ko binds your arrow function, the debugger may be reporting the `this` of the bound function. However, binding a fat arrow function should have *no* effect on its internal lexical this value (bind returns a new wrapper function, arrow functions should behave like a bound function in the first place). Binding an arrow function having *any* effect on its internal this value sounds like a browser bug.